# aetest and google.golang.org/appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I moved a project from the bundled `appengine/*` imports to `google.golang.org/appengine/*`. My test cases still rely on `appengine/aetest`. Unfortunately the `aetest` package hasn't been ported yet to `google.golang.org/appengine/aetest`, which is why I get compile errors because it returns a different context type (`appengine.Context` instead of `x/net/context.Context`) as the bundled packages.

I also can't create a new context, because I'd need a `http.Request` object for that.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Hi , I have the same issue

Comment: Hey Erik. If we are looking into rebundling everything under google.golang.org/appengine/* and the fact that aetest still isn't is causing you issue, maybe posting a defect report (or feature request) on our issue tracker at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list would be a good thing to do? I know the golang team is very active and will look at your request. Obviously don't phrase it like you did here (here you're looking for a workaround, on the issue tracker you'd be reporting an issue), but I think that might be the best way to get help :)

Comment: Well, the GAE team is apparently aware that it hasn't been ported yet, so why poste it as an issue?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work now:

```
import (
  "google.golang.org/appengine"
  "google.golang.org/appengine/aetest"
)

func MyTest(t *testing.T) {
  inst, err := aetest.NewInstance(nil)
  if err != nil {
    tb.Fatal(err)
  }
  req, err := inst.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.whatever.com/", nil)
  if err != nil {
    tb.Fatal(err)
  }
  ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)
  ...
}
```

Comment: As I said `aetest` was not ported at the time. I put in a request that this should be implemented.